# JQuery/Javascript Keyframes Animation: создание рулетки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Здравствуйте.

Я пытаюсь сделать динамический спиннер.
При нажатии на кнопку заработает spinner, после его остановки при нажатии на кнопку запустить с того места, где остановился.

Благодарю за помощь. :)))

code - http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/emjYzb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Такой вариант](http://jsfiddle.net/w6gL5z1r/2/) устроит? Скорость замедлил для наглядности.

```
$(function () {
    var circle = $('#spin'),
        timer;
    circle.addClass('anime').css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
    $('.button').on('click', function () {
        var rTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5001) + 1000;
        if (circle.css('animationPlayState') === 'paused') {
            circle.css('animationPlayState', 'running');
            timer = setTimeout(function () {
                circle.css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
            }, rTime);
        } else {
            circle.css('animationPlayState', 'paused');
            clearTimeout(timer);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Благодарю за помощь,
чтобы работать с таким типом проблем, надо пользоваться animationPlayState?

Comment: @David Kern, надо пользоваться тем, что лучше всего подходит в текущей ситуации, с учетом особенностей задачи ;)